# No module named zipline (Python 64 bit and Windows 64 bit)

Tags: pandas, numpy, zipline

I am unable to use Zipline via import zipline as zp as I get the following error

```
 No module named zipline
```

I also checked python installation on my windows machine and found it is 64 bit

```
import platform
platform.architecture()
```

and i get the following

```
('64bit', 'WindowsPE')
```

I am running python 64 bit on windows 64 bit machine and installed zipline via anaconda

```
pip install zipline
```

and it shows that is successfully installed. However, I still get above error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't install via `pip install zipline`; this is liable to fail for a large number of reasons. Follow [their directions](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zipline) on PyPi and try `conda install -c Quantopian zipline` instead.

Comment: I did try **conda install -c Quantopian zipline** however error is still the same

Comment: I reinstalled anaconda and then zipline and it seems to work for now. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: A lot of packages are being updated right now AFAIK due to some recent updates dropping. It's possible that you tried to install it while the package was still mid-update.